# Compressing a webpage on Apache without gzip or deflate enabled

Tags: php, joomla

I have a joomla site on a shared server consequently I dont have access to apache to enable gzip or defalte so im wondering what i can do maybee with php to enable compression to speed up my site?

Comment: switch your hosting company, your intention will only make your page rendering time much slower then it should be

Comment: Is gzip/deflate really disabled at the moment? Are you 100% sure? Most hosting companies have it turned on to save on traffic bills

Comment: if you're using joomla, it's not page size apparently a bottlenec of your application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to turn on output compression by setting the zlib.ouput_compression setting:

http://php.net/manual/en/zlib.configuration.php#ini.zlib.output-compression

or you can specifically do output buffering and run it through the GZIP handler:

```
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
```

the first option is the preferred method, if you do use the second method check that it doesn't break any ouput buffering Joomla does - I'm no Joomla expert but I would expect a CMS to provide an option to compress content before delivery.

Answer (score 0):

If gzip enabled on your host you need to add this lines to .htaccess file without change your code

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css application/json
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml application/xml text/x-component
```

this lines enables apache deflate in html, css json and xml content

Comment: `I dont have access to apache to enable gzip or deflate`

Comment: He need to create a file named ".htaccess" in www folder and paste this lines. No need to access apache configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you add the condition to check if it accepts encoding like this.

```
<?php
 if (substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip'))
     ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
 else
     ob_start();
?>
```

**Note:**
 you will have to do this for every php file, if your server doesn't support .htaccess configuration.